# Debug Psql block variables from Java Process with Input/Output Streams

Tags: postgresql, debugging, psql, processbuilder

I am trying to run a PgSql block from a Java Process. I have the process output stream
where statements are written and process input stream where the result is retrieved from. Example:

```
["do $$", ""declare x integer:= 12;",
         "declare y integer := x + 4;",
         "DECLARE table_name text := 'foodmart' ;",
         "DECLARE dynamic_sql text;",
         "begin",
          dynamic_sql := 'select employee_id from' || table_name || 'where employee_name = 
                            Mark';
         "raise info '%', dynamic_sql;",
         "execute dynamic_sql"
         "end", "$$;"]
```

These statements are flushed to process output stream one on one.
Only once I close the block with '$$', then only the output is written to std out which is raise info.

I wanted to have something once the dynamic_sql variable is written to stdin,
I should be able to echo dynamic_sql without even closing the block (like real time debugging in java).

There is meta-command in psql \echo but this does not work in psql
do block(Tried this also). Moreover this will still print only once entire block executes.
Is there a way to debug variables in psql and get the resolved values written to std out immediately once the statement is written to outputstream
like in java you can print the value?

Comment: Why are you using PL/pgSQL in the first place? Use individual SQL statements

Comment: Your example is incomplete: in the beginning there should also be a `$$`, and together they form a string literal. The PL/pgSQL is not executed before you finish it, so you cannot get output earlier than that either.

Comment: How would you execute single declare statement as sql without wrapping in a block? I corrected that typo of double dollar. Is there any other way apart from RAISE INFO/NOTICE to debug the variable which dumps to stdout rather than stderr.

Comment: I did not mean a `declare` statement at all. Where do these statements come from? Why not execute a Java program that does `Result x = query("select 12"), y = query("select $1 + 4", [x]); query("select employee_id from "+ tableName + " where employee_name = $2", ["Mark"])` or something?

Comment: Berin, These are part of sql block( Stored procedure, Functions etc.). Once, a variable is resolved by database engine. I need to get the value back and dispatch the result. As we know we can't get it unless entire block is executed. Is there any other way to echo the state in between besides raise notice/info?